# PHP, two singletons inherited from one

Tags: php, singleton

Cant understand how to make singleton static class with ability to create different singleton child classes. The main idea that child classes is own copy of singleton.

I have PdoConnection class like this:

```
class PdoConnection
{
    protected static PDO $dbpdo;

    protected function __construct($mysqlEnv)
    {
        turnDebugMode(false);
        $this->connectPDO($mysqlEnv);
        turnDebugMode(true);
    }

    private function connectPDO(array $mysqlEnv): void
    {
        $dbpdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . $mysqlEnv['host'] . ';dbname=' . $mysqlEnv['name'] . ';charset=utf8',
            $mysqlEnv['user'],
            $mysqlEnv['pass'],
            [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4', PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true]
        );
        $dbpdo->exec("SET time_zone='+3:00';");

        self::$dbpdo = $dbpdo;
    }

    public static function getPdo(): PDO
    {
        self::createSelf();

        return self::$dbpdo;
    }
}
```

And two inherited:

```
class PdoConnectionApi extends PdoConnection
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct([
            'host' => '1',
            'name' => '1',
            'user' => '1',
            'pass' => '1',
        ]);
    }

    public static function func1()
    {
    }
}
```

And second:

```
class PdoConnectionBot extends PdoConnection
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct([
            'host' => '2',
            'name' => '2',
            'user' => '2',
            'pass' => '2',
        ]);
    }

    public static function func2()
    {
    }
}
```

The main problem when I trying create singleton for PdoConnectionApi or PdoConnectionBot, it creates only one singleton.
P.S. Singleton code removed from examples.

Comment: Don't want to question your intend, but if I may ask: Why do you need static singletons? Don't you just need two different PDO connections?

Comment: I dont different. I need to use in my child classes methods of parent.

Comment: Yes, but there's two things: Class hierarchy (like _extends_) and Object hierarchy (how you put everything together, what goes where). I added an answer, maybe this is better to read.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick shot, maybe you need to elaborate a bit more in the question, but from the question so far if I get you right, the culprit is:

```
      protected static PDO $dbpdo;
```

In specific that the property is a static property. This allows you only one instance per class hierarchy.

What you want is one instance per object hierarchy that can be multiple from that one class hierarchy.

It is pretty straight forward to change, modify the base-class and change the property:

```php
class PdoConnection
{
    # static removed, change it now into a real object property,
    # protected visibility kept.
    protected PDO $dbpdo;

    protected function __construct(array $mysqlEnv)
    {
        ...
    }

    private function connectPDO(array $mysqlEnv): void
    {
        $dbpdo = new PDO(...);

        ...

        # assignment to the object property
        $this->dbpdo = $dbpdo;
    }

    ...
```

This should solve it. You can now create as many singletons as you like, they all have their PDO instance.

### Next Steps:

- Consider to make the class *abstract* as you have template code in there and you want it to be extended.
- Consider to make the constructor public, have a factory class that knows how to create a PDO from array $mysqlEnv, then directly injects a PDO $dbpdo in the contructor, assigning to $this->dbpdo. (This is a refactoring to *dependency injection* and this will highly likely solve your initial problem of getting the instances created.)
- Consider lazy-loading: A connection to the database is only necessary when there is need to actually query it. (This is a design question how you'd like to handle this, depends on how your project works.)